# I have been getting issue abput clipping

Tags: topology

[image]

I filled gap area with edges but nothing has changed. Why is this happening and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the faces on the top have inverted normals, i.e. they are inside out. Turn on *Viewport Overlays > Face Orientation* in the *3D Viewport*. The inside/back of faces is shown in red, the front/outside is blue. They should all be blue on your object.

To set the correct orientation, select the affected faces (or maybe even all) and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals*.

[image: face orientation overlay]

Comment: Thanks it worked out easly. I had a same on chess set so I was doing same thing but it was a little bit complicated than should be. blue ones turns out red and red ones runs out blue when I selected all and press shift n. So I selected inividually and pressed shift n each of them. Is it normal or is there a quick way to do. In addition inside selection just making it worse

Comment: Ideally it should function correctly. By recalculating the normals all outside faces should be blue, or if you check the option _Inside_ they should all be inverted and turn red. If they are mixed red and blue that's mostly indicating that there is something else wrong with the geometry... but that could be lots of things from open geometry so that Blender can't decide if it's outside or inside to maybe double vertices/edges/faces etc.